# How to use SMOTENC inside the Pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imbalanced-learn, smotenc

I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know how to use [SMOTENC](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTENC.html).  I wrote:

```
num_indices1 = list(X.iloc[:,np.r_[0:94,95,97,100:123]].columns.values)
cat_indices1 = list(X.iloc[:,np.r_[94,96,98,99,123:160]].columns.values)
print(len(num_indices1))
print(len(cat_indices1))

pipeline=Pipeline(steps= [
    # Categorical features
    ('feature_processing', FeatureUnion(transformer_list = [
            ('categorical', MultiColumn(cat_indices1)),

            #numeric
            ('numeric', Pipeline(steps = [
                ('select', MultiColumn(num_indices1)),
                ('scale', StandardScaler())
                        ]))
        ])),
    ('clf', rg)
    ]
)
```

Therefore, as it is indicated I have 5 categorical features. Really, indices 123 to 160 are related to one categorical feature with 37 possible values which is converted into 37 columns using `get_dummies`.

I think `SMOTENC` should be inserted before the classifier `('clf', reg)` but I don't know how to define "`categorical_features`" in `SMOTENC`. Besides, could you please let me know where to use [imblearn.pipeline](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#module-imblearn.pipeline)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I'm not familiar with the concept.

Comment: Kari nakardam  :)

Comment: @Media Hi, I installed Pycharm+Anaconda on a different system. However, I don't know how to resolve this error: `no python interpreter configured for the project` Thanks a lot.

Comment: The reason is that anaconda uses its own distribution of python. There are numerous solutions, you can a instal a separate independent python and specify its path in the pycharm. Or you can simply type spyder in your cmd and use your current anaconda in spyder IDE.

Comment: @Media Hi. Nowruz Mobarak.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much and for you too :)

Comment: @GreenFalcon Hi. Nowruz Mobarak

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot. You as well :)

Comment: @GreenFalcon Hi, could you please answer this [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/128230/how-to-obtain-predictions-for-all-observations-in-a-dataset)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it follows, two pipelines should be used:

```
num_indices1 = list(X.iloc[:,np.r_[0:94,95,97,100:120,121:123]].columns.values)
cat_indices1 = list(X.iloc[:,np.r_[94,96,98,99,120]].columns.values)
print(len(num_indices1))
print(len(cat_indices1))
cat_indices = [94, 96, 98, 99, 120]

from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

pipeline=Pipeline(steps= [
    # Categorical features
    ('feature_processing', FeatureUnion(transformer_list = [
            ('categorical', MultiColumn(cat_indices1)),

            #numeric
            ('numeric', Pipeline(steps = [
                ('select', MultiColumn(num_indices1)),
                ('scale', StandardScaler())
                        ]))
        ])),
    ('clf', rg)
    ]
)
pipeline_with_resampling = make_pipeline(SMOTENC(categorical_features=cat_indices), pipeline)
```