# how to obtain predictions for all observations in a dataset?

Tags: predictive-modeling, data-science-model, ranking

I have a dataset comprising 1864 roads with various traffic and safety features, along with the number of accidents at each road. The objective is to rank these roads based on the number of accidents. Could you please advise me on whether to pursue an explanatory or predictive modeling approach for this problem?

If I opt for a predictive approach, should I utilize nested cross-validation to predict the number of accidents at each road? In this method, hyperparameters would be tuned in the inner loop, and predictions obtained in the test set of the outer loop, resulting in a model count equal to the number of outer loops.

Alternatively, I could split the dataset into a holdout test sample and a train set, perform cross-validation on the train set to tune hyperparameters, and then evaluate performance on the holdout test set, potentially using it to compare different regressors. Finally, I would obtain predictions for the entire dataset using the fitted model. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @ebrahimi. Have you used the stratify parameter for train_test_split in sklearn?